# Could this code potentially run into an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, qt, concurrency

Is it possible for this Qt code to run into an infinite loop?

```
QNetworkAccessManager m;
QNetworkReply *reply = m.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.example.org/")));
QEventLoop loop;
QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop.exec();
qDebug() << reply->readAll();
delete reply;
```

This is basically a "synchronous" way to display the contents of a webpage.

I have not observed any issues using it, but I considered the following scenario:

- The `finished` signal of `reply` is emitted *before* the event loop is created and the signal-slot connection between `finished` and `quit` is made
- No signal will be emitted from that point forward thus never triggering `quit`
- `loop.exec()` will continually loop

Is it possible for that to occur, or am I not understanding something about how the Qt event loop works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Qt executes your own code (the code above, for example), it can't process new signals and call slots. Every signal was emitted while your method is executing will be processed later. If you want to force processing of signals in middle of your method, you can call [QCoreApplication::processEvents](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) to process signals in your current event loop or [QEventLoop::exec](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qeventloop.html#exec) to do it in another loop.

So this code is safe. If a signal comes too fast, it will wait in the event queue.

If you're emitting a signal and there are slots connected to this signal using [Qt::DirectConnection](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum), these slots will be executed immediately. But this doesn't match your case. Qt have to execute some internal code before the singal will be emitted. It can't execute this code while your method is executing. There are only one thread and only one call stack.

Note that when you're using Qt threads event loops' behaviour is more complicated.

Comment: "will be processed later". Incorrect. "When a signal is emitted, the slots connected to it are usually executed immediately" See [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html). I think you're confusing signals and events. Signals emitted within same thread are processed immediately, using `QMetaObject::activate`->`qt_static_metacall`, so improper signal handling CAN result in infinite recursion and stack overflow.

Comment: Yes, I wrote about this. But this only can happen when this code is emitting the signal. But if the code, executing in the moment, isn't related to QNetworkReply, it (or its nested function calls) can't emit QNetworkReply's signal. And no one else can emit this signal in the same time.

Answer (score -1):

Just before running `loop.exec()`, you could check `reply->isFinished()`. If it is, just don't execute the loop.

Comment: Wrong, QNetworkAccessManager::get won't even start processing created request until it gets to event loop